# JavaScript scrollTop scrolling to wrong div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So, I am dynamically adding a "side navigation" bar using JavaScript. It has circles, which when clicked, will take you to a certain DIV on the page. For some reason, it isn't scrolling to the correct div.

For example, I have a div Circle1, which when clicked, should you the user to the top of the page. BUT, it is taking the user to the div A (which should be scrolled to when Circle2 is clicked).

Basically, every onClick function for each of my circles is off by 1. Here is JSFiddle to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/zu6516eu/9/

Any ideas? Thanks

```
 document.getElementById('Circle1').onclick = function() {
    scrollToTop();
  };
```

**Full Code**

```
var offset = 0;

//initialize side nav bar
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  var SideBar = document.createElement("Div");
  SideBar.setAttribute("id", "SideBarNav");
  SideBar.style.color = "white";
  SideBar.style.display = "inline-block";
  SideBar.style.position = "fixed";
  SideBar.style.top = "50%";
  SideBar.style.right = "0";
  SideBar.style.transform = "translate(-50%, -50%)";
  SideBar.style.textAlign = "center";
  SideBar.style.border = "2px solid rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.5)";

  var Circle1 = document.createElement("Div");
  Circle1.innerHTML = "&bull;";
  Circle1.setAttribute("id", "Circle1");
  Circle1.style.textAlign = "center";
  Circle1.style.fontSize = "3.5em";
  Circle1.style.margin = "0 auto";
  Circle1.style.opacity = ".7";
  Circle1.style.color = "blue";
  Circle1.style.lineHeight = ".5em";

  var Circle2 = document.createElement("Div");
  Circle2.innerHTML = "&bull;";
  Circle2.setAttribute("id", "Circle2");
  Circle2.style.textAlign = "center";
  Circle2.style.fontSize = "3.5em";
  Circle2.style.margin = "0 auto";
  Circle2.style.opacity = ".1";
  Circle2.style.color = "blue";
  Circle2.style.lineHeight = ".5em";

  var Circle3 = document.createElement("Div");
  Circle3.innerHTML = "&bull;";
  Circle3.setAttribute("id", "Circle3");
  Circle3.style.textAlign = "center";
  Circle3.style.fontSize = "3.5em";
  Circle3.style.margin = "0 auto";
  Circle3.style.opacity = ".1";
  Circle3.style.color = "blue";
  Circle3.style.lineHeight = ".5em";

  var Circle4 = document.createElement("Div");
  Circle4.innerHTML = "&bull;";
  Circle4.setAttribute("id", "Circle4");
  Circle4.style.textAlign = "center";
  Circle4.style.fontSize = "3.5em";
  Circle4.style.margin = "0 auto";
  Circle4.style.opacity = ".1";
  Circle4.style.color = "blue";
  Circle4.style.lineHeight = ".5em";

  SideBar.appendChild(Circle1);
  SideBar.appendChild(Circle2);
  SideBar.appendChild(Circle3);
  SideBar.appendChild(Circle4);
  document.body.appendChild(SideBar);

  document.getElementById('Circle1').onclick = function() {
    scrollToTop();
  };
  document.getElementById('Circle2').onclick = function() {
    scrollFunction(A);
  };
  document.getElementById('Circle3').onclick = function() {
    scrollFunction(B);
  };
  document.getElementById('Circle4').onclick = function() {
    scrollFunction(C);
  };
  offset = jQuery(".row.span_24").height();
  console.log(offset);
});

function scrollFunction(targetString) {
  var target = jQuery(targetString);
  if (target.length) {
    console.log(offset);
    var top = target.offset().top - offset;
    jQuery('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $(target).offset().top - 15
    }, 'slow');
    return false;
  }
}

function scrollToTop() {
  jQuery('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: 0
  }, 'slow');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because of the way you're trying to reduce the gap between the circle divs by reducing the line height.  Subsequent divs are overlapping the previous one, so whilst it looks like you're clicking the top, you're actually clicking the second etc.

[Here is an updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kav5gp9s/1/) that gets around the problem by not using massively scaled up bullet points - it uses a circular div instead.

```
#Circle1, #Circle2, #Circle3, #Circle4 {
    background-color:blue;
    height:10px;
    width:10px;
    border-radius:5px;
    margin:2px;
}
```

Comment: I realized it is line-height: .5em; that was making the div mess up. here is the fiddle without line-height: http://jsfiddle.net/zu6516eu/15/ what is the best way to reduce the gaps between? Thanks a lot

Comment: @Harry see my updated answer/fiddle - the issue was more around using the huge font size for the bullets.  Using this method means you're not trying to make something big small again - it's just rendered as it should be

Comment: Thanks. I'll check it out. Would there be an easier way to implement this entire thing to avoid this problem?

Comment: Probably - but that's starting to get out of scope of this question!  When you get something together that works, you can always post it over at [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) for comments on how to improve it :)

Answer (score 1):

The issue was you didn't have enough document at the end of your webpage for the scrollTo to properly align.  So it would scroll to the lowest point it could before the end of the page prevent any further vertical scrolling.  I added about 20 or so more

```
<p>Hello</p>
```

to the end of your fiddle's HTML and updated.  Now when you click the circles the DIV B and DIV C align perfectly at the top.

Answer (score 0):

Just simply use a html anchor to scrool on click to right place.

HTML:

```
<div class="element"><a href="#test">Go to test</a></div>
<div id="test"></div>
```

JQ:

```
    var $root = $('html, body');
    $('.element a').click(function() {
        var href = $.attr(this, 'href');
        $root.animate({
            scrollTop: $(href).offset().top
        }, 500, function () {
            window.location.hash = href;
        });
        return false;
    });
```